# Excel Format Conditioning Input issues

Tags: excel

I'm stuck on this issue I am having with excel conditional formatting using color change.

**What works:**

I set the format for A1 to change colors when specific text is placed. Then I set B1 to change color in accordance with the color from A1  `=AND(A1="G",B1="")`. 
Colors change and everything works perfectly.

**What doesn't work:**

When I type something into the B cell, the color goes back to white. I do believe that there is a conflict in my code, but I'm just now teaching myself the difference between absolute and relative conditioning.

What code string should I use to keep the color of B1 to stay the same with A1, but also let me type into B1 with text?

Thanks yall!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work it out...
**you can click "other regular" menu. then select "only use formula confirm..."**

if you fill the formula "=AND(A1="G",B1=""" in cell B. then it ok!

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In your formula you are asking B1 to be empty "". When it is not empty because you type something, of course the `AND` will return `FALSE`.

Comment: I want B1 to stay any color that A1 is designated according to formatting, while giving me the ability to type whatever I want into B1

Comment: Then use for B the same rule you used for A

Comment: Basically I am trying to build a calendar based sheet that has 4 coded days with their own respective colors. When the value is placed in one column I want the row of the neighbor column to change with it respectfully. The neighbor column would be set to have anything placed into it without changing the color of its own cell.

Comment: I hope that makes some sort of sense

Comment: Its already set as the rule that when A1 changes, it changes to the same color. But when I type into the B1 cell, to place a name of a person, it changes back to white

Comment: BOOM! You my friend are a genius. Ive been working on this code, my brain skipped through it